# Play Console Error : an active app bundle was uploaded before you choose your app signing key

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

[Error Message From Google Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeBG9.png)

### can someone kindly tell me why this is happening?

the file we upload from generate bundle signed, my friend already publish without error but when we try to publish again with different account after change (com....) to other we got this error

Comment: Did you figure it out in the meantime? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: no, still can't figure it out. it works fine if you create a new keystore, but don't know if there are any side effects. i mean we should always create a new keystore which is we gonna need maintain alot of keystore to update our apps.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking through my Play Console and found somewhere that I just need to upload a new app bundle and then it just worked fine.